# Convert a fluid nested flexbox grid to stacked for mobile

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am using the [CSS3 Flexible Box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for a cross device site.

I have an existing flexbox layout for the desktop devices, like so:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.nested-wrapper1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50%
}

.nested-wrapper2 {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="nested-wrapper1">
      <div class="1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nested-wrapper2">
      <div class="2">2</div>
      <div class="3">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I create a fluid layout for mobile devices where only 1,2 are in a grid and 3 should be stacked below 1,2; refer the following image:

[image: Fluid Nested Flexbox]

Comment: Do you want 3 should be 100% width?

Comment: @DavidGenger Yes 3 should be 100% width for mobile devices, Below 1,2 who are both having 50% width respectively.

Comment: Its a bit different

Comment: Flexbox is intended for one-dimensional layouts. This would be better built using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a way with a `flexbox` - assuming the mobile view is below 650px, *position* the third div *absolutely* relative to the `wrapper`.

A possible issue can be that the third div fully overflows the `wrapper`. Well, check out the demo below:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.nested-wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.nested-wrapper2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.nested-wrapper1>[class='1'] {
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
}

.nested-wrapper2>[class='2'] {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 1em;
}

.nested-wrapper2>[class='3'] {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .nested-wrapper2>[class='2'] {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nested-wrapper2>[class='3'] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nested-wrapper1">
    <div class="1">
      1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-wrapper2">
    <div class="2">
      2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
       2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </div>
    <div class="3">
      3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. You are awesome :)

Cheers and Thank you!!

There is one slight issue with the 3rd div on mobile devices, since the position is absolute it is overlapping the div below, I have fixed that by giving a padding to the div which was hidden behind which is equal to height of div 3. There might be an elegant solution which I am not aware yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `display:contents` and a media query.

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gGbZdB)

[**Display:contents @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.
>
> Turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements also have their display turned off.

**Support**...is poor. Chrome 58 & FF37 - No IE/Edge/Opera/Safari

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.nested-wrapper1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 50%
}

.nested-wrapper2 {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%
}

.r-2 {
  background: red;
}

.r-3 {
  background: yellow;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .nested-wrapper2 {
    display: contents;
  }
  .l-1,
  .r-2 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  .r-3 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nested-wrapper1">
    <div class="l-1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nested-wrapper2">
    <div class="r-2">2</div>
    <div class="r-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this and your Insights. Works for Mozilla at the moment. Obviously this is a lot cleaner but as you stated above - it does not provide cross browser support at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

While the OP has asked for a flexbox solution, and as I'm not aware that you can do that layout with flexbox, you could use floats.

Depending on the content and the needed proportions of the elements this approach may or may not work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flexo {
  height: 200px;
}
.flexo > div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 66.66666%;
}
.flexo > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flexo > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: deeppink;
}
.flexo > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.flexo > div:nth-child(3) {
  height: 33.33333%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media ( min-width: 480px ) {

  .flexo > div:nth-child(1) {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .flexo > div:nth-child(2),
  .flexo > div:nth-child(3) {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }  

}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexo cf">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer works well if we use floats, Thank you for your time and insights :)